# Cufon Not Working

Tags: javascript, fonts, cufon

Can anyone tell me why Cufon isn't working on the following page: [URL removed]

I've used Cufon numerous times in the past and now that I'm at a point where the project is ultra time sensitive I run into an issue.  Web Inspector in Safari is telling me:

"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Cufon"

All of the files are linked up correctly, so I'm really at a loss. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I don't think those Javascript files are even interpreted as such. From what I can see there are no "Content-type" headers (e.g. "text/javascript") set on them.

FWIW, jQuery which is included on that page is not defined either.

Comment: Ya know what? It was a spelling error on my part. After coding for 15 hours straight, some dumb mistakes are bound to be made.  Thanks for giving me a new angle to approach this problem from.

Answer (score 2):

This error can also occur if you load Cufon after you've loaded a font that requires it.